# Changing data type of column for synced table

Tags: carto

A synced table I setup against the 311 dataset at data.cityofnewyork.us works great!

However, the date columns come over as string, preventing me from doing date functions in queries, and from using the date columns in a Torque visualization.

I successfully issued an ALTER TABLE command to change the data type to date, but when the table is synced against source, the date columns revert back to string.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a dynamic query to a synced table. As in,

```
SELECT *, normally_text::int normally_text_as_int FROM table_name
```

Now, your column `normally_text` comes back also as a column named `normally_text_as_int` formatted as an integer.

```
int
text
numeric
```

Will be the key recasting methods. For dates you may need to read up a bit here, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html