# Casting data types from GeoJSON feed

Tags: geojson, carto

Just getting started with the CartoDB Way and have run up against first problem which is similar to [Changing data type of column for synced table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83095).

We have a GeoJSON feed coming from a Fulcrum data collection app. We want to see current results of that collection on a map, so I have set up a GeoJSON feed from Fulcrum as a starting point.

Over in CartoDB, I create a table and provide the GeoJSON URL.

The data appears, all as strings, except for the_geom.

I want to create a sort of "set and forget" transform process so that the column types are always converted properly and made available to CartoDB as their correct data types.

What is the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't see any specific documentation, it appears that once a column type is set in CartoDB subsequent refreshes to the same table do not unset the column type.
So even though we're still getting "string" columns from Fulcrum, those columns are updated in CartoDB without changing the column types assigned in CartoDB.